# Multiple SVGs interaction performance

Tags: performance, dom, svg

Does SVG performance degrade with the number of separate SVG elements in the DOM ?
I would like the draw a whole bunch of little SVG images which will not need any interaction, but I also have one "main" SVG which will need interaction. As I add more non-interactive SVGs, will the performance of the main one get worse ?

Comment: The best answer to this is always to try it and see.  The answer may depend on exactly how you use it.  I suspect you will probably be okay though - assuming that "a whole bunch" is not hundreds or thousands.

Comment: You will always have better performance with canavs or webGL for any type of particles, and hundreds of images animating. Canvas and WebGL always are better at rendering massive amounts of elements. But DOM and SVG based elements will always perform slower with many multiple elements. Since canvas and webGL basically take snapshot on every requestAnimatonFrame, whereas DOM/SVG based elements have to be constantly calculated, layout, painted, and composited even if rendered on the GPU, especially on Safari. But test and see, to see at what point performance gets affected.

Comment: "The best answer to this is always to try it and see" - I asked the question because I don't have time and wanted to know from anyone who knew the answer already

Comment: "You will always have better performance with canavs or webGL" I know, but that's not what I asked

Comment: You forgot to add my last bit in that quotes sentence `for any type of particles, and hundreds of images animating.` SVG performance does degrade with the number of separate SVG elements, since it its DOM based. And is subject to layout, painting, and compositing .. see http://csstriggers.com/  .. Also it depends on how many elements you are animating and what attributes / CSS properties you will be animating as well. Here is an example of animating `a whole bunch` of SVG elements, If you bump up the `circleCount`, you will see performance degrade.  http://codepen.io/jonathan/pen/EVgYbB :)

Answer (score 0):

OK I made two SVGs, one with hundreds of elements and one with nothing. Interaction with the blank SVG was noticeably slow when the 2nd SVG was in the DOM, even if it was hidden.